# How to ask an user to re-confirm password but prevent browser to autocomplete or autofill saved password

Tags: html, authentication, autocomplete, passwords, autofill

I want the user to re-confirm their password before he can perform some sensitive function (e.g. deleting a record permanently).

The user has saved his login username/password in Chrome, so whenever the user is required to re-confirm his password, Chrome will prompt "Use password for [username]" to see if he wants to use saved password for the field.

Have tried autocomplete autofill = off without success. Any thoughts?

Comment: By "autocomplete autofill = off" do you mean: `autocomplete autofill = off` or `automplete="off" autofill="off"`?

Comment: yup... haha sorry... should have written in proper syntax

Comment: Yeah it's fine. I just had to make sure in my answer because there's a lot of total noobs on SO... But I'm glad the second part helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you tried:

```
autocomplete autofill = off
```

However, you need to make sure you do:

```
autocomplete="off" autofill="off"
```

(as two separate attributes). Otherwise this would set `autocomplete` as `true` (default).

---

And, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917221/2397327), using `autocomplete="false"` on a `<form>` is now not working on Chrome. See his workaround:

According to that answer, Chrome will automatically assume any `<input>` right before a password is a username. So put hidden (`display: none`) `<input>`s before the real inputs to fool Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I did use proper syntax... :) Cool, the answer works, thanks. I start to wonder how Google implement their authentication when user try to change account settings, it requires user to re-confirm password... I don't think they need to use a dummy input field...

Answer (score 1):

Practically autocomplete="false" or autocomplete="off" doesn't work, at least in google chrome.

So I use this `autocomplete="new-password"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Make sure the password textbox has a different name/id to any other used.
2. Use autocomplete="false" on both the FORM and the INPUT box

Certain versions of Chrome have some issues around autocomplete.

See: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153